# In Wordpress, how do I display a single random post of a custom post type in a sidebar widget?

Tags: wordpress, random, widget, sidebar, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type - Testimonials - for a WP site I am working on. I want to display a single random testimonial in my sidebar - without using a plugin if possible. Do I need to create a text widget with the proper post query? If so, what would it look like?

Many thanks,

Cynthia

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want you can directly paste following code snippet in your `sidebar.php` where you want to show the `Testimonials` (make sure whether it's `testimonials/Testimonials`)

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type'=>'testimonials', 
    'orderby'=>'rand', 
    'posts_per_page'=>'1'
  );

  $testimonials=new WP_Query($args);

  while ($testimonials->have_posts()) : $testimonials->the_post(); 
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); // or the_content(); ?></p>
<?php 
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: I tried putting your code into an advanced text widget that allows php and got  an error so I played with it and ended up modifying it to this:

<?php
$args=array('post_type'=>'testimonials', 'orderby'=>'rand', 'posts_per_page'=>'1');
$testimonials=new WP_Query($args);
while ($testimonials->have_posts()) : $testimonials->the_post();
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
<?php    
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

Your post pointed me in the direction I needed so thanks tons!

Comment: @Cynthia If you want really random, not always the same content add `remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');`So, it will look like this in your code: `<?php remove_all_filters('posts_orderby'); $args=array('post_type'=>'projects', 'orderby'=>'rand', 'posts_per_page'=>'2'); $projects=new WP_Query($args); while ($projects->have_posts()) : $projects->the_post(); ?> <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p> <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`